# Copy source code from github to docker container in Jenkins

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, build, pipeline

I have a source code in my github. I built a free style job in jenkins and gave the git repository in the SCM section. I need to write a shell script to copy this source code into a container running outside. Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You have 3 components: git origin, jenkins, separate host on which docker container is started, right? And you'd like to initiate a pull of git origin docker container from Jenkin's job?

Comment: Yes I have Github on one container and jenkins on another container. Now using jenkins free style job I need to copy this source code on github to another container.

Comment: Is your "GitHub" your "Git Server" but not github.com or GitHub Enterprise?

Comment: Are you further aware how containers usually work, i.e., that they involve an image building process instead of being updated? Because from what I read in your question and comment, it sounds to me you miss some basic understanding of containers (or it's just a language barrier).

Comment: It is github.com in a container

Comment: Yes I know how containers work. I worked on them

Comment: Hi *YashRao*. Marcin Pietraszek answer could be help you. Did you try? Also what about the *approach 2* of my answer? If your source code is in rare host (you cannot connect by ssh) , you can expose an http endpoint to deploy you app or source code. What are your source code programming language?

Comment: I tried scp command but the hostname of docker is not identified. The source code programming language is Python3. My source code in in Github which again is a container. I am running jenkins in another container. My problem is to copy this source code to another container. I need help

Comment: Your jenkins is able to clone the source code? If yes, you could clone it inside the app container (according to your requirement, you don't need to clone it inside your jenkins). Also you can  expose an extra /deploy endpoint (developed in python)  in your app container to allow jenkins upload your code. Check this diagram https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/static_resources/master/deploy_endpoint.png

Comment: The source code is present in jenkins workspace inside jenkins container. I did not understand what you said. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Did you see the attached image?

Comment: Option 1: Clone the source code inside of your python container. Option 2 : Implement an upload functionality in your python container. Jenkins could use this functionality to upload your source code.

Comment: @YashRao In almost all real cases, Jenkins or any CI server must require some type of communication with target servers like, tomcat, jboss, containers, etc.  Your current approach is not the best option in real environments (like I said in my answer). I suggest you install your Jenkins in the host machine and access to all docker containers will be easy. Also you must decide if you have a tens of scripts, complex Dockerfiles or a devops flow inspired in some saas.

Comment: I cannot install jenkins in my host. I am trying to be isolated. I tried docker cp, scp, rsync but none of them worked

Comment: Is just a proof of concept or is your testing/production environment?

Comment: proof of concept. Dev and prod are containers

Comment: Is your jenkins for production environments is also inside a container?

Comment: yes, jenkins is also in an container

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

In almost all real cases, Jenkins must require some type of communication with target servers like, tomcat, jboss, containers, etc

In case of tomcat or jboss for java applications, this servers expose an http endpoint which allow to remote clients (like jenkins) or plugins, upload build artifacts to deploy them.

In case of docker solutions, jenkins must be able to connect to docker host in order to execute docker commands like docker build, run , etc

In case of saas solutions like heroku, openshift, etc , all of infrastructure complex is managed by them. Developer user only need to push the source code.

Here some approaches

**Approach 1: Copy files from jenkins host to container**

This is an example of how copy files from host to living container

`docker cp /file/in/host/foo.txt mycontainer:/foo.txt`

Execute this line from jenkins to local docker (If your jenkins is in the same host of your docker container) or remote in remote linux ( in case of jenkins and docker are in differents machines).

In the second case (remote docker), all code must be cloned in remote machine also.

Maybe you can zip the source code, before copy it to container.

> Jenkins must have access to the docker in order to execute docker commands.

**Approach 2 : Deploy endpoint**

- Develop a container which expose an endpoint called **/deploy**. This endpoint receive your artifact like java or just file like php, nodejs, etc.
- From jenkins , send the artifact , executing an http request to **/deploy**
- Other ideas : /deploy must return success or failure in order to detect the status of deployment

This approach is clean because you don't need crazy shell scripts to pass artifacts or source code to a living docker container.

> In this case, Jenkins does not need a low level communication (ssh) with your docker container. Even your container app could be deployed in other cloud like amazon, azure or google.

**Approach 3 : Clone source code inside container**

- Create a docker image with ready configurations like : ssh-agent, git, language (java, node, etc), etc
- Clone source code inside container at build or run stage
- When image is builded or launched, execute this tasks in this order : clone source code, build and start.
- Jenkins will just build or launch this image `docker run ...` sending parameters like git_url, etc.

> Jenkins must have access to the docker in order to execute docker commands.

**Approach 4 : Create something like heroku or openshift**

- Implement the **Approach 3**
- Detect git push event using webhook configurations in jenkins: (https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks)
- When push event is detected, jenkins must detect programming language of repository and will launch your cool docker image of **Approach 3**.
- Notify deployment result by email or something like that.
- Make it open source

Comment: How closely do you think is this related to the original question?

Comment: @JRichardsz, thanks for your detailed explanation. I tried Approach 1 but the problem is docker in docker. I am running jenkins on docker container. So copying the code from jenkins to another container is the task. I installed docker in container and tried docker cp but it did not work. My problem is to copy source code to another container using a jenkins job. Can you please hel;\p

Comment: YashRao, let's think of a more elegant solution :D

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that (based on your comment):

- You have container in which you have a git bare repository (A)
- You have container in which you have jenkins installation (B)
- You'd like to clone/checkout code from (A) in (B)

On container B you need:

- Create ssh key pair
- After setting up A, clone code by executing `git clone ssh://username@containerA/path/to/repo.git`

On container A you need:

- Create user `username`
- Copy public key generated on B to `username`'s `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Expose 22 port

Comment: Containers having SSH running.. please don't abuse containers ;)

Comment: you are right about A and B containers. I wanted to push code to another container C using jenkins job

Comment: @StephenKing could you please suggest "the container way" of solving that?

Comment: Read a docker tutorial and you will learn that you build new images for new application versions. So Jenkins would build a new image and push it to a registry. This image is then launched instead of the previous one.

Comment: @StephenKing but that's contratictory to what jenkins is doing. Jenkin's job is to download actual code to workspace and execute tests/do other stuff with it. Code that's part of a jobs shouldn't be part of jenkins image as you can't predict during image building how many jobs would be there. Building jenkins' image for each of its jobs' git repositories update is not the way to go. Container A in this place is basicaly a github respotitory to which you can authenticate via ssh - this is the only reason for which this port is exposed.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the Jenkins image, but that Jenkins builds a new image for the application that is downloaded from CVS, built and tested.

Comment: OP isn't using CVS. He's using GIT which is inside other container. How would you like to download that code from the other container different than exposing 22/443 on it?

Comment: sorry, meant VCS ;)